# Trouble with progressbar in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, progress-bar

This is my code

```
janela_barra=Toplevel()
janela_barra.title("Processando...")
janela_barra["bg"]="light grey"
janela_barra.minsize(width=400, height=80)
janela_barra.maxsize(width=400, height=80)
comprimento = janela_barra.winfo_screenwidth()
altura = janela_barra.winfo_screenheight()
x = (comprimento/2)-(400/2)
y = (altura/2)-(80/2)
janela_barra.geometry("400x80+%d+%d" % (x, y))
janela_barra.iconbitmap('icon6.ico')
pb = ttk.Progressbar(janela_barra, orient=HORIZONTAL, length=200, mode='determinate')
pb.grid(column=0,row=0)
pb["value"]=0 
pb["maximum"]=100
```

and then there is this inside a for:

```
for i in range(0,tamanho):
    pb["value"]=i
    pb.update()
```

where tamanho is the number of iterations of a for(420 right now), but the thing is, it only opens a windows and then closes, i can't see the progressbar actually function, no matter how much i increase tamanho

Comment: That loop will run in probably just a few milliseconds, so it sounds like it's behaving as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Just add `sleep` (from module `time`) in your loop, you will see the progression. Here is an example:

```
from tkinter import Tk, Button, Toplevel
from tkinter import ttk
from time import sleep

root = Tk()

def fct_run_for():
    top=Toplevel(root)
    top.title("Progression")
    pb = ttk.Progressbar(top, orient="horizontal", length=200, mode='determinate')
    pb.grid(column=0,row=0)
    pb["value"]=0 
    pb["maximum"]=100
    for i in range(100):
        pb["value"] += 1
        pb.update()
        sleep(0.1)

Button(root, text="Run", command=fct_run_for).pack()
root.mainloop()
```